# How do I set TextBlock height

Tags: wpf, xaml, height, textblock

How do I bind the height of `TextBlock` to the height of the parent control?

I have a `TextBlock` inside a grid and I want the `TextBlock` `Height` & `Width` to be the height & width of the grid cell without hard coding the values.

Cheers

AWC

Answer (score 2):

[Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) is the easiest way:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  
  <Viewbox>
   <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
   </Viewbox>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers, Anvaka

Answer (score 0):

When a textbox is in a grid it gets its measures from the measures of the grid cell.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try on `TextBlock`:

```
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Which is by default!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is what u are looking for :

```
<Grid >
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBlock x:Name="SelectedUserName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ></TextBlock>
 </Grid>
```